# OOM using CRON but not using SHELL

Tags: java, linux, shell, ubuntu, cron

When I start a java program with high memory usage ("-Xmx52g") by shell, everything is working well. However if I start the same program with the same command and same user by CRON, I get a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError just after a few seconds.

Additionally CRON isn't able to do anything as long as I don't kill the blocked java program. No matter which cronjob should be started, it always ends up with "(CRON) error (can't fork)" in syslog. After killing the java program all new cronjobs are working fine again.

The problem only occurs with Ubuntu 16.04, all older versions worked very well. Is this a bug or a new security feature? I didn't find any information about this issue, so I hope anyone may help.

Comment: Sounds like cron has a shared memory limit between itself and its spawned children... perhaps a cgroup limitation?

Comment: I think you might be right. But would this be a bug or something I could/must solve myself? I use a plain 16.04 Ubuntu server image out of the box without any customization.

Comment: Well, it's possible that a limit was established to prevent runaway cron jobs from taking down the system. As to how to configure that limit, I'm not sure if there are system-specific tools or config files. Probably you should ask on serverfault since this isn't a programming question and is really off-topic for stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

You need more RAM or size to launch it

http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/09/javalangoutofmemoryerror-permgen-space.html

Comment: The server has enough RAM (128 GB) and everything is fine as long as I use any older Ubuntu but not 16.04 (but even there it works fine if I start the program by SHELL and not by CRON). It doesn't seem to be something that could be solved by any java configuration, since CRON itself is completely blocked after it starts the java program. For instance if CRON should start a simple "hello world" perl script it also fails with "(CRON) error (can't fork)" in syslog. It seems like CRON itself has some kind of memory limit. But why and how to adjust?